# Counterexample of Residue theorem. Complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Can someone explain why the word 'FINITE' is necessary and provide a counterexample when the word 'finite' hasn't been included?
Let $U$ be a simply connected open subset of the complex plane $CONTAINING$ $A$  $FINITE$ list of points $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ (none of which are on the curve $\gamma$), and let $U_0 = U \setminus \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$. Let $f$ be a function holomorphic on $U_0$. Letting $\gamma$ be a closed rectifiable curve in $U_0$, and denoting the residue of $f$ at each point $a_k$ by $\operatorname{Res}(f, a_k)$ and the winding number of $\gamma$ around $a_k$ by $\operatorname{I}(\gamma, a_k)$, the line integral of $f$ around $\gamma$ is equal to $2\pi i$ times the sum of residues, each counted as many times as $\gamma$ winds around the respective point:

$$
\oint_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^{n} \operatorname{I}(\gamma, a_k) \operatorname{Res}(f, a_k).
$$

If $\gamma$ is a positively oriented simple closed curve, $\operatorname{I}(\gamma, a_k)$ is $1$ if $a_k$ is in the interior of $\gamma$ and $0$ if not, therefore

$$
\oint_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i \sum \operatorname{Res}(f, a_k),
$$

with the sum over those $a_k$ inside $\gamma$.

Comment: You can't have infinite set of points. Suppose it is infinite, then we can consider $g=f^{-1}$ function. It goes to zero in points of the mentioned set. It is infinite subset of a bounded domain, so by the uniqueness theorem $g$ mush be identical zero everywhere in this domain what leads us to a contradiction

Comment: @EgorIvanov boundedness is not assumed anywhere. The statement is fine even if there are infinitely many $a_k$’s, provided we assume they’re all isolated points of the domain $U$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo If domain $U$ is unbounded it doesn't have any boundary curve $\gamma$

Comment: @EgorIvanov $\gamma$ is not a boundary curve of $U$, it is just some curve in $U_0$ (for example $U=\Bbb{C}, a_1=0,U_0=\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ describing the unit circle, so we can consider the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ and apply the theorem to this situation).

Comment: You can have infinitely many points but you have to make sure that (1) they do not accumulate at $\gamma$, (2) only finitely many have nonzero winding number with respect to $\gamma$.

Comment: Another problem with @EgorIvanov 's argument (where evidently $g=\frac{1}{f}$ was intended) is that the points in the set *need not be poles* -- e..g. they could be essential singularities.  The key point for OP is that these points $a_k$ must be isolated.  OP is working with a simplified form of residue theorem -- that is why a finite set was specified and why $U$ is a simply connected domain, instead of a Domain where the curve (/cycle) satisfies Artin's Criterion.

Comment: @EgorIvanov what about the case when $f$ doesn't equal to zeroes in points it just doesn't defined there. In this case you can't say anything about zeroes of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @GorMelkumyan If singularity is removable, it doesn't make sense to think about it as singularity. If singularity $z_0$ is not removable, then $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)=\infty$ according to Laurent series expansion.